# Flask's url_for function does not get interpolated within html code

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route( '/log=<page>' )
def log( page ):
....
....
# add counter to html template and start rendering
counter = '''<center>
            <table bgcolor=black bordercolor=orangered>
                <td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών     </font></td>
                <td><a href="http://superhost.gr/log=%s">       <font size=3 color=plum> %d </font></a></td>
            </table>
        ''' % (page, pagehit)
```

Why the above code cannot be written as follows. It doesn't get interpolated.

```
# add counter to html template and start rendering
counter = '''<center>
            <table bgcolor=black bordercolor=orangered>
                <td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών     </font></td>
                <td><a href="<a href="{{ url_for('/log', page='%s' }}">">   <font size=3 color=plum> %d </font></a></td>
            </table>
        ''' % (page, pagehit)
```

Also when i try an inline statement to avoid for block i get an error. It should have worked.

```
name = nikos if (5>3)
```

Comment: I assume when you say it doesn't get interpolated your html has the {{url_for as a string, try passing it as a text substitution outside of the text, otherwise it will get written as a string and not evaluated

Comment: I'am a bit confused over this. Please show me how.

Comment: Well, can you show me the resulting html? (it is hard to understand what you mean by interpolated)
Also you should use a template, I think jinja is the default for flask, there you put your html and it will render it for you including variables etc. In my experience modifying html as a string leads to a lot of headaches.
What I tried to say is that your expression {{url_for will NOT get evaluated as it is inside a string, the string will appear as is, you need to put it in a template or evaluate it OUTSIDE the string and substitute it in the string

Comment: i do use index.html as flask template but its not its place to there. Can you show me how to evaluate it outside of the string? you are right its dumb to except it to be evaluated(that what i meant by interpolate) within a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pass the variable to the template and have the {{url_for inside your template, then the rendering engine will take care of that IIRC (RECOMMENDED)

Or you can evaluate it like:

```
counter = '''<center>
            <table bgcolor=black     bordercolor=orangered>
                <td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών     </font></td>
                <td><a href="{url}">   <font size=3 color=plum> {number} </font></a></td>
            </table>
    '''.format(url={{ url_for('/log', page=page) }}, number=pagehit)
```

Also you have a bug in the second code you post it says

```
<a href="<a href="{{ url_for('/log', page='%s' }}">">
```

Comment: It works it has to be 'log' not '/log' as the argument we are passing is the name of the function log(). Right? i wrote it like this: `# add counter to html template and start rendering
 counter = '''<table bgcolor=black     bordercolor=orangered>
     <td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών: </font></td>
     <td><a href="%s"> <font size=3 color=plum> %s </font></a></td>
    </table>
   ''' % ( url_for('log', page=page), pagehit )` i use backticks in comments i dont know why the code isnt properly formatted sorry about that. also ctrl-k dont owrk in comments.

Comment: Glad to see it helped, if this answered your question mark it as the good answer please.

Comment: Also if you please tell me how cna i use url_for within my template to write this: "http://superhost.gr/cgi-bin/<variable_here>.py"

Comment: Lol I get paid a lot for coding, you better buy me a beer someday.
Inside the template just do {{ url_for() }}/{{variable}}.py should work, be careful with quotes etc.
THIS IS IN THE TEMPLATE, NOT IN YOUR STRINGS.

Comment: If you come to Greece 2 beers on me for your behalf my friend!! Promise!! Yes within templates we need {{}} lets say i want in my template to access page files.py. How would i wrote it? `<a href="{{ url_for() }}/pelatologio.py">' But what must be inside the url_for as argument?

Comment: I'am trying it like this `<a href="{{ url_for('/cgi-bin/pelatologio.py') }}">` for accessing http://superhost.gr/cgi-bin/files.py but its not working.

Comment: Well yes, that looks like the way to go:

<a href="{{url_for('/cgi-bin')}}/{{script_name}}.py"> 
Then remember to pass to the template the variable script name

Comment: I'm just tryint to use url_for from within my templates to link to specific files. `<a href="{{ url_for('/cgi-bin') }}/files.py"> ' though gives `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/cgi-bin'. Did you mean 'index' instead?`

Comment: In general url_for() is used when we know a callback fuction name or it also can be used to point to specific links as well?

Comment: So in your code you have @app.route( '/log=<page>' )
def log( page ): that's why you have url_for('/log'), if you want to use cgi-bin you need an endpoint with the @app.route etc if that is what you are asking

Comment: Yes. url_for('/log') does not work only url_for('log') works as the argument to be pass is the function name 'log' not the endpoint '/log'. url_for() is used when we know a callback function name or it also can be used to point to specific links as well?

Comment: as per the documentation:
flask.url_for(endpoint, **values)
Generates a URL to the given endpoint with the method provided.
So YES, you need to define the callback function (@app.route('cgi-bin') for instance

Comment: so as an argument it only receives callback function names and not pure links?

Comment: if you want to generate a url for another page NO, that's not what it is meant for, it gives you the url for the endpoints in YOUR website that you have declared, but if http://yourserver/cgi-bin is declared (you can access http://yourserver/cgi-bin because there is some @app.route('cgi-bin') in your routes then you can use it, one thing I don't understand is why you are passing the python scripts as urls

Comment: I'am just learnign on the go and iam experimenting along..... So you mean to use a directory i.e. 'cgi-bin/' i have to create a function for it? Otherwise i cannot access that folder to get a specific cgi-file?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do now:
You have a bunch of cgi-bin files, and want the users to be able to access/download them right?
Then you can create an endpoint that results in the user downloading the file there for each file, if that is what you are trying to do of course.

Comment: Yeap! That's the idea. i have a bunch of files not cgi but text files that i want the user to be able to downlaod them one by one. i have a cgi script ready from the past but now that iam turning into flask i need some way to access those files the flask way. Don't tell me that for every folder i want to utilize i need to create endpoints and callback funtions!!!